# How to access elements from an array of structure

Tags: c

I have:

```
struct strType{
     char *str1;
     char buff[128];  
    };

struct strType sType[3] = {
                            "String1", "",
                            "String2", "",
                            "string3" ""  
                           };
```

How can I assign a string to buff?
My requirement is that I need two parallel strings one which is predefined and other which is decided on run time. I am thinking of using array of structures. But not able to use them.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing the `buff` part of an instance of `struct strType` inside the array is done with `sType[index].buff`. Copying the string can be done with standard `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(sType[0].buff, "String to put in buffer");
```

**However**, it's much safer to use `strncpy` when copying data into fixed-size buffers like this (because otherwise you open up possibilities for buffer overruns and someone crashing or taking control of your process):

```
strncpy(sType[0].buff, "String to put in buffer", sizeof(sType[0].buff));
```

Comment: Please! Use strncopy (or another 'safe' variant) when possible.

Comment: @jv42, @houbysoft: Rushed to answer. Amended now :)

Comment: There is no advantage of using strncpy() in this particular case, as the size of the buffer and the input are both known at compile time. The input is even a string literal residing in read-only memory. The only thing achieved with strncpy() is a few more CPU ticks of overhead code. Avoid religious dogmas like "strncpy is good, strcpy is bad" and use whatever function that is most appropriate from case to case.

Comment: @Lundin: How do you know that the size of the input is known at compile time? The OP doesn't say which is which.

Comment: @Jon I'm assuming the fixed size array will contain the one which is known at compile time, or the code really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So, is the declaration I made correct? I mean *str1 is a pointer.

Comment: strncpy fills the target array with zero bytes (which takes unnecessary time), and does not guarantee it is zero terminated, which means it's not really safe, it's just a bit easier to avoid buffer overruns.

Comment: @Lundin Even if the string is known at compile time, if in some semi-distant (ie 1 month) future, someone reuse the code and puts a much longer text, boom. Granted, it's not likely, but having good habits beats debugging buffer overruns.

Comment: @Coder It is probably correct, if you intend to have str1 point to a dynamically allocated string.

Comment: @Lars That statement contradicts itself. A zero byte == a nul termination. strncpy fills up the target with nul termination bytes, so the result is guaranteed to be _incredibly_ nul terminated :)

Comment: @jv42 Or in the future, someone could reduce the buffer length of both source and destination strings, but not change the `size_t n` parameter to the strncpy call. Equal boom. strcpy() would have prevented that from happening, as it doesn't fill up the target strings with nul characters. So yeah, if someone adds bug to any kind of code, the code will not work...

Comment: @Lundin, sorry if I was unclear. strncpy does not guarantee the target array is zero terminated, but fills any unused bytes with zeroes. This means it's both unsafe and slow at the same time. Anyone who really cares about this, uses a helper library that keeps track of string lengths and array sizes itself, and allocates more memory as needed.

Comment: @Lars But it does guarantee that, since it fills up unused bytes with zeroes. Simply strncpy() the correct number of bytes: one more than the source string's length. strncpy(dest, "AB", 3); rather than strncpy(dest, "AB", 2); However, this is not safer than strcpy(), but it is slower and harder to read.

Comment: @Lundin, please read the `strncpy` manual: it does not guarantee. If the source string is longer than the destination array, there is no terminating zero byte.

Comment: @Lars I did actually read up on both functions in the standard before posting. No matter: if the source string is longer than the destination array, no C function will save you. strcpy(), memcpy(), strcat() etc will all fail as bad as strncpy() and start to write out of bounds.

Comment: @Lundin, quite correct: C string handling functions require one to check the target size before calling, even `strncpy` (and if you do that, `strncpy` isn't buying you much). `snprintf` is probably the best one of the lot. The best solution, however, is to use a helper library that takes care of allocating and managing memory, and keeping track of string lengths. Doing it manually all the time is just a recipe for error.

Comment: Guys back to the original question...char *str1; is a pointer to a statically allocated string...can someone verify the declaration please...@Lundin str1 is not allocated memory dynamically.....I assume as we are allocating strings in array of a structure sType...

Comment: @Coder It works even if it's a statically allocated string. Just don't point at a string literal or the pointer should be declared const char*.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for firstly initializing an array of structs. In that case your code should look like this:

```
struct strType{
     char *str1;
     char buff[128];  
    };

struct strType sType[3] = {
                            { NULL, "String1" },
                            { NULL, "String2" },
                            { NULL, "string3" } 
                          };
```

You can then use *strncpy* as in [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508067/how-to-access-elements-from-an-array-of-structure/6508106#6508106) to copy a string to `strType.buff`. Note that you will have to allocate memory to `strType.str` before you can copy a *string* to it.

Comment: this is good but he is also asking how to assign to the buffer later.

Comment: Why would you initialize a statically allocated array with NULL? Does this even compile? Didn't you actually mean {NULL, "String1"} ?

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, I actually meant {NULL, "String1"}. Thanks, for pointing that out. No, I did not compile, or even tried to, because it's too simple. Shouldn't have hurried to answer.

Comment: @0A0D: I have updated my answer to link to Jon's answer for strncpy.

Answer (score -2):

You need to initialize the struct like this:

```
struct strType sType[3] = { {"String1", " "},{"String2", ""},{"string3", " "} };
```

And then you can use strcpy as Jon mentioned once you have your string with you

Comment: You don't actually need to have a null-terminated string in the destination buffer to use strcpy(). I'm not sure what you mean by "have your string with you".